# Ambiguous 'this' inside jquery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is the context of 'this' inside jquery callback.

```
$('input').on('change', function(){
    this.number = $(this).val();
});
```

Above, this is the input element, which is normally what we want 'this' to be. The problem is that when it becomes a method of an object as below.

```
// constructor pattern
var View = function(){
    this.number = 0;
};

// method definition
View.prototype.foo = function(){
    $('input').on('change', function(){
        // former this should be the object instance and 
        // the latter should be the html element.
        this.number = $(this).val(); 
    });
};
```

To change the context of this of the function, Function.bind() can be used as below.

```
View.prototype.foo = function(){
    $('input').on('change', function(){
        this.number = $(this).val(); 
    }.bind(this)); // bind the callback to the instance of View object
};
```

Above works until $(this).val() since then $(this) wants the input element back not the View object.

In order to solve this in ad-hoc manner, I can explicitly set this to be the name of an instance as below.

```
View.prototype.foo = function(){
    $('input').on('change', function(){
        // explicitly set this to be the instance
        // while sacrificing generality since code breaks when the object name is not 'view' 
        view.number = $(this).val(); 
    }); 
};

var view = new View();
```

As you can see, this can resolve ambiguity of this but also compromises generality since code breaks when the object name is not 'view'.

Given above, how can I make the code resolve ambiguity while not compromising generality? 
Please suggest a way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common approach used in many lib/frameworks is as following:

```
View.prototype.foo = function(){
    var self = this; // store this as a local variable
    $('input').on('change', function(){
        self.number = $(this).val(); 
    }); 
};
```